# Agent-state forever pending or no tools available

Tags: 14.04, juju, maas

I am doing maas with juju ( Ubuntu 14.04 server), so after I bootstrapped the environment(maas in my case) I lost internet access somehow:

[image]

I got bzr to download charms (mysql and wordpress). I had 3 nodes comissioned and on ready state.
Then on the maas server where juju is installed I did the following:

juju add-machine two times, one for the mysql and the other for wordpress, after that I deployed the charms and waited for 1hour and nothing happened, I am doing something wrong ?
I just want wordpress and mysql working, please help me with these issues!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tools available means that the bootstrap node can't access the outside world (or that agents can't reach the bootstrap node). There are ways around this for getting bootstrap up, see:

- [Configure Proxy Access](https://jujucharms.com/docs/howto-proxies)
- [Set up a Private Cloud using Simplestreams](https://jujucharms.com/docs/howto-privatecloud)